# Why the output is different in this list comprehension?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary-comprehension

When I Execute the following code it works correctly:

```
hassam="CHECK"
list1={i:hassam[i] for i in range(5)}
list1
```

output:

```
{0: 'C', 1: 'H', 2: 'E', 3: 'C', 4: 'K'}
```

but when i execute this:

```
hassam="CHECK"
list1={hassam[i]:i for i in range(5)}
list1
```

output:

```
{'C': 3, 'H': 1, 'E': 2, 'K': 4}
```

why isnt this:

```
{'C': 1, 'H': 2, 'E': 3,'C' : 4 ,'K': 5}
```

Comment: can't have two duplicate keys in a dictionary, last one wins

Comment: First example can be written as `dict(enumerate(hassam))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the dictionary :

```
{0: 'C', 1: 'H', 2: 'E', 3: 'C', 4: 'K'}
```

the numbers being the key is not same.
But for the dictionary

```
{'C': 1, 'H': 2, 'E': 3,'C' : 4 ,'K': 5}
```

python doesn't allow duplicate keys. Therefore the key is updated with the new value.
Here, it showed so because dictionaries cannot have same keys with diffrent values. So try using `list1` as a list like:

```
list1=[{hassam[i]:i} for i in range(5)]
```

This would give:

```
[{'C': 0}, {'H': 1}, {'E': 2}, {'C': 3}, {'K': 4}]
```

Or a tuple instead of individual dictionaries:

```
list1=[(hassam[i],i) for i in range(5)]
```